# How to disable data-ajax for whole page in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i have made html page using jquery and it has many links in it but when i click on navigation href links, it shows error message " error loading page" , i have found solution for that if i put data-ajax="false" then error goes ,so what is causing this error and what to do to solve this error and is there any way to make data-ajax="false" to whole page without implementing it to every href links?

```
<li> <a href="me/about.html" data-ajax="false">About Developer</a></li>
```

if i use the above code then it works fine

Comment: Can you show it in fiddle?

Comment: Provide more code then. (including your javascript as well as HTML)

Comment: see this i dont it help you or not this http://jsfiddle.net/DQ7xp/

Comment: I don't see any errors there

Comment: i have uploded my project in sky drive check it http://1drv.ms/1cUBTqt in that when you click on about developer link it does not show error but when you click on "..... get started it shows error because data-ajax=false is not written it that link so whats the problem @Pavlo did you get it

Comment: because there is not such file `/images/java/about.html`. There is even no such folder `java`

Comment: i HAVE just showed you demo , i know that i want to tell that when you click on "....get started link" it shows error message instead of going to any page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47754/discussion-between-smart-developer-and-pavlo)